# Google Script: Play Sound when a specific cell change the Value

Tags: javascript, audio, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Situation:**

[Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Om6334YNxmNfTIGrARShNY0VD74zdNlKprem_UJneec)

> Sheet: Support 
>   Column: H has the following function **"=IF(D:D>0;IF($B$1>=$G:G;"Call";"In Time");" ")"** that changes the value depending on the result.

**Problem:**

I need to:

> 1. Play a sound when a cell in column H changes to "Call" on the sheet "Support".
> 2. This function will need to run every 5min.
> 3. Does the sound need to be uploaded to Drive or can I use a sound from a URL?

I will appreciate to anyone can help on it... I see a lot of code but I didn't understand very well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty tough problem, but it can be done with a sidebar that periodically polls the H column for changes.

**Code.gs**

```
// creates a custom menu when the spreadsheet is opened
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Call App')
    .addItem('Open Call Notifier', 'openCallNotifier')
    .addToUi();

  // you could also open the call notifier sidebar when the spreadsheet opens
  // if you find that more convenient
  // openCallNotifier();
}

// opens the sidebar app
function openCallNotifier() {
  // get the html from the file called "Page.html"
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page') 
    .setTitle("Call Notifier");

  // open the sidebar
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}

// returns a list of values in column H
function getColumnH() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Support");

  // get the values in column H and turn the rows into a single values
  return sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
}
```

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="message">Checking for calls...</p>

    <audio id="call">
      <source src="||a URL is best here||" type="audio/mp3">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    <script>
    var lastTime = []; // store the last result to track changes

    function checkCalls() {

      // This calls the "getColumnH" function on the server
      // Then it waits for the results
      // When it gets the results back from the server,
      // it calls the callback function passed into withSuccessHandler
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (columnH) {
        for (var i = 0; i < columnH.length; i++) {

          // if there's a difference and it's a call, notify the user
          if (lastTime[i] !== columnH[i] && columnH[i] === "Call") {
            notify();
          }
        }

        // store results for next time
        lastTime = columnH;

        console.log(lastTime);

        // poll again in x miliseconds
        var x = 1000; // 1 second
        window.setTimeout(checkCalls, x);
      }).getColumnH();
    }

    function notify() {
      document.getElementById("call").play();
    }

    window.onload = function () {
      checkCalls();
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some sources to help:

- [Sidebars and Dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Simple Trigger - `onOpen`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callback).customFunction()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Great is Working... But I hava a question, the sidebar not clear when the sound end. Is possible close automatically when the sound end?

Comment: No, the sidebar needs to stay open so it can keep checking column H with `window.setTimeout(checkCalls, x)`. Maybe you could style the sidebar more and add more functionality so the user has more reasons to keep it open.

Comment: Josh, I found this funtion google.script.host.close() but i can find the way to use it... The sound need 2 sec for run... I trying to find the way to execute google.script.host.close() after 5 sec... this funtion close the sidebar

Comment: Use an event handler that triggers when the audio has finished playing: [W3 Schools `onended`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/av_event_ended.asp)

Comment: I found the code...
Is there any way that the audio sounds even though it is not in the browser flap where I have the spreadsheet open? Because it only sounds if I'm on the flap where I opened that spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't see the app script code to connect to / trigger the javascript in the html     function notify() {
      document.getElementById("call").play();
    }

Answer (score 2):

Recursively calling checkCalls() eventually led to errors, when I implemented the main answer given (which is mostly correct and really useful, so thank you!).

// Note: But the original implementation would work fine for a while - say 90 minutes - then crash.  The call that would normally take 1 second would take 300 seconds, and Execution would Halt.  It looks like it blew the stack by keeping on recursively calling itself.  When moved to a single call of check() with proper exiting of the function, it then worked.

The console log in Chrome on running the JavaScript, said this:
ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR.QUIC_TOO_MANY_RTOS 200

After much investigation, I worked out a better way of doing it...  Which doesn't require recursion (and therefore won't blow the stack).

Remove this line:
// window.setTimeout(checkCalls, 500);

And use something like this - at the end of your script:

```
  // This function returns a Promise that resolves after "ms" Milliseconds

        // The current best practice is to create a Promise...
  function timer(ms) {
   return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  }

  
  async function loopthis () { // We need to wrap the loop into an async function for the await call (to the Promise) to work.  [From web: "An async function is a function declared with the async keyword. Async functions are instances of the AsyncFunction constructor, and the await keyword is permitted within them. The async and await keywords enable asynchronous, promise-based behavior to be written in a cleaner style, avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains."]
    for (var i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
      console.log('Number of times function has been run: ' + i);
      checkCalls();
      await timer(3000);
    }
  }


  window.onload = function () {
    loopthis();
  }

</script>
```