# Google Script play sound globally

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to play a sound in Google Spreadsheet and others viewing this sheet should also be able to hear it. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad. Please add more details about how the sound will be played and a brief description of your search / research efforts as it's suggested on [ask].

Comment: Maybe possible with a side bar / modal dialog html service. Not directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Script: Play Sound when a specific cell change the Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881605/google-script-play-sound-when-a-specific-cell-change-the-value)