# Playing a sound when a new entry is done on Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, audio, triggers

Is there a way to play a sound whenever there is new data entered by a user in certain cell? The use case is to give a sound notification to the user just like Uber app gives a sound notification to the driver when there is a ride request.

More specifically: when Col_1 has been changed, my code records day and hour of this change in Col_2. I need my code also notify of this change with a sound in real time.

This is my code:

```
function onEdit(event){

  var Col_1 = 11;
  var Col_2 = 12;

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Planilla madre") {
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == Col_1) {
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),Col_2);
    var timestamp = new Date();
    switch (state) {
      case "":
        // 
        adjacent.clearContent();
        break;
      default:
        // 
        adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
        break
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want the computer to go "ding" or whatever each time someone enters info into a cell? Did this not work? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881605/google-script-play-sound-when-a-specific-cell-change-the-value if not please show your code so we can find the problem. If it does work, delete this question. If I don't understand what you are asking, clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I clarified my question.

Comment: Have you thought about using SpreadsheetApp's `toast` function to show a little toast slide out notification? Many users mute audio, can't hear, or don't like audio notifications.

Answer (score 1):

As right now there seems to be no way to actually play sound the way you want.

You could look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep) but this will need to actually create an HTML page to display it as [dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs). Using [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) seems to not work either in Apps Script.

But sincerely to create a dialog to serve HTML with audio the solution of @IMTheNachoMan and using [`toast`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg) to show a little pop out for every edit you want to notify.